How do I format currency strings in go?
I'm trying to convert a float64 currency '1000.99' to the string '£1,000.99'.  The currency is not always £, and I'd like to decoration to be language/region specific (e.g. some places format it as '£1.000.99', others might do '£10,00.99'.
I have the ISO codes for the currency and the language, and I've found the package golang.org/x/currency, but the documentation doesn't really state how it actually works.  So far I have the following:
func Format(val float64, currency, language string) (string, error) {
    unit, err := currency.ParseISO(currency)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    amount := unit.Amount(val)

    // I know I need to call amount.Format(state, rune), but I have no idea how to create a state or a rune?
}

How do I construct a state and rune for a given ISO language?

Unrelated to your original question, but do not use floating point for currency. Floating point values are for scientific computations. They are not exact.

You don't use amount.Format directly, but via a message.Printer (Go Playground):
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/text/currency"
    "golang.org/x/text/language"
    "golang.org/x/text/message"
)

func main() {
    amount := currency.GBP.Amount(1000.99)

    LangPrint(language.English, amount)
    LangPrint(language.German, amount)
}

func LangPrint(t language.Tag, amount currency.Amount) {
    p := message.NewPrinter(t)
    p.Printf("%v: %v\n", t, amount)
}

prints
en: GBP 1,000.99
de: GBP 1.000,99

